# how to set alarm to osmdroid when closer to boundary

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am developing an application in which I need to use **maps offline**. I'm using osmdroid and osmbonuspack
I have implemented code to display user's current location. And display boundary by importing KML content.
How can I set alarm to notify user, when user come closer(about 50m-100m) to that boundary?[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30RI2.png)

Comment: You'll need [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the distance and when user comes in the pre-set range you need to call alarm manager class which will trigger a notification

Comment: Do I need to calculate distance from current location to each point!!! It will take too much time to process, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can buffer the area by (50m, 100m) and use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) `#addProximityAlert()` to set a trigger.